How low can temperature be on chicken broth on the stove
I make bone broth with chicken bones. Over night, how low can the temperature be and still be safe?

It’s a function of time and temperature. You need to estimate how long the soup stayed in the danger zone between 40 and 140°F / 4 and 60°C, i.e. cool enough that bacterial growth can happen. See our generic Q/A.

Further to Stephie's comment, I'd also suggest that it might be worth attacking the issues from another angle. Perhaps you should look at ways of cooling the broth quickly, so it can be refrigerated over night.
